# Making dot optional with limited characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying the following Regex and It is failing

```
/^\d{1,18}[.]?$/
```

I want digit 1-18 but a optional dot(.) anywhere. I tried the following too

```
  /^[1-9]{1,18}[.]?$/
```

It counts . as a character as well i.e 12345678901234567.

How can I achieve 18 digits and an optional . anywhere in regex

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex with a lookahead to block 2 dots:

```
^(?!(?:\d*\.){2})[.\d]{1,18}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/41I4WB/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!(?:\d*\.){2})`: Negative lookahead to disallow 2 dots
- `[.\d]{1,18}`: Match dot or digit for length range between 1 to 18
- `$`: End

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?=(?:\.?\d){1,18}\.?$)\d*\.?\d*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FObw9a/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:\.?\d){1,18}\.?$)` - a positive lookahead that requires 1 to 18 occurrences of an optional `.` and any digit followed with an optional `.` at the end of string
- `\d*\.?\d*` - 0+ digits, an optional `.` and again 0+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: wow this is amazing. I never knew there was `(` and `)`. what does it do? Can I add `[^-]` so it doesn't need negative value at all?

Comment: @Nofel There is no need for `[^-]` because `\d*\.?\d*` does not match `-`. `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions), used to group or quantify sequences of patterns. `(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) used to define context rather than match and consume characters.